# Reading a CSV of strings and formating it without quotes or brackets

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a CSV file that goes

```
header
1
2
3
4
5
```

when I pass it through this

```
import csv

with open('saferlist1.csv') as csvfile:
    saferreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for n in saferreader:
        print(n)
```

I get

```
['header']
['1']
['2']
['3']
['4']
['5']
```

how can I make it so that there's no square brackets or quotes

I am very non-technical so sorry if this question is worded poorly

Comment: Each `n` is a **row** of csv data, and a row is a Python `list`. The elements of each row are strings, and when you print a list it adds quotes around the string items, they are not part of the string however. Since each row in you example has only one element, you can verify what I'm saying by using `print(n[0])` to display the first element of each one, and there will not be any quotes since your will be print a string, not a list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import csv

with open('saferlist1.csv') as csvfile:
    saferreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for n in saferreader:
        print(n[0])
```